# How do I format a Mustache conditional inside string for Mustache HTML rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, mustache

I have an HTML string that I would like rendered as HTML in Mustache. However, that string also contains a Mustache conditional. When I inspect the rendered HTML in Chrome Dev Tools, it seems that the conditional is literally being printed inside the input element, instead of being handled. I think it might be a problem with the forward slash in the closing brackets. In Chrome Dev Tools, the / is removed upon rendering. So I tried using the HTML decimal code. That also did not work.

This is where I am rendering the HTML string:

```
<span>{{{response.additionalInfo}}}</span>
```

This is the object I am passing to the view. The additionalInfo property is the one that has the embedded Mustache conditionals:

```
var response = {
                templateType: "optIn",
                header: "Opt-In",
                additionalInfo: "<label><input type='checkbox' id='notOptIn' name='isOptIn' {{^response.isOptIn}}checked{{/response.isOptIn}}> YES</label>",
                isOptIn: false,
}
```

Is it possible to add a Mustache conditional inside a string that Mustache will render as HTML? If so, how do I escape the / in the ending tags?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't manage to make it work with a single call to Mustache.

For what it's worth, I managed to make it work by converting the template in `response.additionalInfo` and storing the result in `response.additionalInfo`.

Then I converted the template you provided.

With `isOptIn = false` :

```js
var response = {
    templateType: "optIn",
    header: "Opt-In",
    additionalInfo: "<label><input type='checkbox' id='notOptIn' name='isOptIn' {{^response.isOptIn}}checked{{/response.isOptIn}}> YES</label>",
    isOptIn: false,
}

var template = "<span>{{{response.additionalInfo}}}</span>";

document.getElementById("run").addEventListener("click", function() {

    response.additionalInfo = Mustache.to_html(response.additionalInfo, window);

    html = Mustache.to_html(template, window);
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = html;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://mustache.github.io/extras/mustache.js"></script>

<button id="run">Run</button>
<div id="container"/>
```

With `isOptIn = true` :

```js
var response = {
    templateType: "optIn",
    header: "Opt-In",
    additionalInfo: "<label><input type='checkbox' id='notOptIn' name='isOptIn' {{^response.isOptIn}}checked{{/response.isOptIn}}> YES</label>",
    isOptIn: true,
}

var template = "<span>{{{response.additionalInfo}}}</span>";

document.getElementById("run").addEventListener("click", function() {

    response.additionalInfo = Mustache.to_html(response.additionalInfo, window);

    html = Mustache.to_html(template, window);
    document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = html;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://mustache.github.io/extras/mustache.js"></script>

<button id="run">Run</button>
<div id="container"/>
```